# Adding REST authentication to Grails + SpringSecurity browser app

Tags: rest, authentication, grails, spring-security

I have a Grails app in STS 3.1 with a REST API laid out in UrlMappings.groovy and a group of controllers. I installed the SpringSecurity stuff so I have Login/Logout controllers and RegistrationCodeController etc. I have been using the browser interface to login but I need to start logging in from a REST client.

What are the specific urls and requests I need to use to register / login / check logged in / logout?

I have been able to login by POSTing j_username and j_password to /j_spring_security_check. But, if I first make a request which fails authentication, then POSTing to /j_spring_security_check automatically returns the results of the initial, failed request. I need a way to login that always returns success/error status and User.id on success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Config.groovy, insert some config items:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = "/rest/success"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.failureHandler.defaultFailureUrl = "/rest/failed"
```

This will force successful login to be redirected to /rest/success. Then in this method, return the user.id:

```
import grails.converters.JSON
class RestController {

    def springSecurityService

    def success() {
        def response = ['status':'success', 'id':springSecurityService.currentUser.id]
        render response as JSON
    }

    def failed() {
        def response = ['status': 'failed']
        render response as JSON
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see why this should work. Unfortunately, when I first request a controller that needs auth, then I POST to /j_spring_security_check, I am still redirected to the response from the first request. Should I be logging in by some other request instead of POST to /j_spring_security_check ?

Comment: I think post to it is fine, given that original auth login form has the same thing. Does it work in web page direct login scenario?

Comment: defaultTargetUrl redirect works for web page login but not for POST from my rest client.

Comment: Is that request an Ajax one? Then you should define `successHandler. ajaxSuccessUrl` and `failureHandler. ajaxAuthFailUrl`. Post some code to the question may be helpful.